# Read a binary file through FileReader in browser and send it properly to server

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, spring-mvc, filereader

I'm trying to do the following:

1. Read a binary file through FileReader.
2. Send the file to server.
3. Read the file in server.

The main questions are at the bottom.

**Read a binary file through FileReader and send to server:**

I'm using angular, but I don't believe it's relevant so unless someone will ask me to I'll remove the boilerplate code, except for the call to the server. Since FileReader readAsBinaryString is deprecated, I'm using readAsArrayBuffer like so:

```
$resource(myurl, {}, 
            { 
                post: {
                     method: 'POST',
                     params: {},
                     isArray: false,
                     headers:{'Content-Type':'application/octet-stream'}}
             });

var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function() {
    resource.post({}, reader.result);
};
```

When this code runs, I see in the network tab the data seems to pass correctly. The post data contains a byte array for example of length 400 bytes.

**Read the file in the server**

I'm using this code to read in the server

```
@POST
@Path(myPath)
@Consumes({"application/zip"})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response myRest(@QueryParam("file-name") String fileName, InputStream file) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int bytesRead;
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        while ((bytesRead = file.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] data = output.toByteArray();

    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

When I debug, I see a completely different result than the byte array I've sent. For example, while I've seen in the browser network a 400 byte length array, in the server I see 10 byte length array.

1. Am I reading the file correctly in the client? Is readAsArrayBuffer the method I should be using?
2. Any idea why am I getting different results in the server? Should I consume a different media type? Or maybe I should send different headers?

Thanks!

Comment: You can skip the _FileReader_ step entirely, `Object.getPrototypeOf(File.prototype) === Blob.prototype`, you can submit a file just like it were a _Blob_

Comment: Thanks @PaulS. it works! I owe you a cake. So what you suggested was changing the way I read\send the file in the client. Pure out of curiosity, do you know what change I should've done in the server (or in the headers I send in the client) if I wanted to still read the file using FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer and get it correctly?